# Where are located the routine and the result features matched in OpenDroneMap?

Tags: python, matching, feature-selection, odm, structure-from-motion

I'm not an expert in pyhton, and I'm looking for where is located the routine and the result of the matching features of the images in OpenDroneMap. Because I want to create or add a sub routine who select random features matches of all the final features matched, before go to the next SfM step who computes the 3D sparse structure

someone Knows where I can find this to add this routine?

the OpenDroneMap used is the branch: master
https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenDroneMap